# Deep link into a Facebook canvas app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I am embedding a Facebook app `https://example.com` into the Facebook app canvas so that it is available at `https://apps.facebook.com/EXAMPLE` . My application sends notification emails that contain links like `https://example.com/messages/123` and that should open the page embedded into the Facebook canvas. How do I achieve this? My current thoughts:

1. User opens `https://example.com/messages/123`
2. Application checks for [`signed_request` parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)
3. Application redirects user to `https://apps.facebook.com/EXAMPLE/?requested_page=/messages/123`
4. Application checks for `requested_page` parameter and redirects to this page
5. User sees `https://example.com/messages/123` URL and is embedded into canvas

Is there a better pattern out there to get this working?

**My final working solution (with Ruby on Rails)**

1. User opens `https://example.com/messages/123`
2. Application checks on client-side if app is embedded in canvas:

   ```
   if(window == top){
       top.location = "https://apps.facebook.com/#{Settings.facebook.app_id}#{request.fullpath}";
   }
   ```
3. User is redirected to `https://apps.facebook.com/EXAMPLE/messages/123`
4. Application middleware converts `POST` into `GET` if `signed_request` is present (code and idea borrowed from https://github.com/dekart/facebooker2/blob/master/lib/facebooker2/rack/post_canvas.rb)
5. Application parses `signed_request` with fb_graph gem

   ```
   FbGraph::Auth.new(app_id, app_secret, :signed_request => params[:signed_request])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just update the link to point to `http://apps.facebook/example/messages/123` off the start.

When you check for authentication just set the redirect after authorization/login to the same page.

Redirecting a user around multiple pages for no reason is just not a good practice.

Comment: When I link to https://apps.facebook/example/messages/123 , then https://example.com/messages/123 is opened with a POST request. That's the reason why I thought using requested_page parameter might be better...